# Google Analytics is not receiving all data from Data Layer via GTM

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer, enhanced-ecommerce

I'm working with Enhanced Ecommerce at the moment; getting data from a site for Google Analytics but not everything is working.
The cart tracking (payment and shipping) is working and I can see this on Google Analytics, but Tracking Product Clicks, Measuring Views of Products, Tracking Additions to Cart, and Tracking Removals from Cart are not working as they should.

When I load certain parts of the pages, the Data Layer is not populated with any data using the following code:

```
    //Tracking Product Clicks
        dataLayer.push({
           "event":"EEproductClick",
           "ecommerce": {
             "currencyCode": curr,
             "click": {
               "actionField": {"list":"category" },
               "products": [{
                 "id": pdc,
                 "name": GarmName,
                 "price": prix,
                 "brand": "MyBrand",
                 "category": ""
              }]
            }
          }
        });
//End


//Measuring Views of Product Details
        dataLayer.push({
           "ecommerce": {
             "currencyCode":curr,
             "detail": {
               "actionField": {"list":""},     //optional list property
               "products": [{
                 "id":pdc,
                 "name":GarmName,
                 "price":prix,
//               "brand":"Boss",
//               "category":"Men/Clothing/T-Shirts",
//               "variant":"black"
              }]
            }
          }
        });
//End

//Tracking adds to cart
        dataLayer.push({
           "event":"EEaddToCart",
           "ecommerce": {
             "currencyCode": curr,
             "add": {
               "products": [{
                 "id": pdc,
                 "name": GarmName,
                 "price": prix,
                 "brand": "MyBrand",
//               "category":"Men/Clothing/T-Shirts",
//               "variant":"black", //optional, if there is a variant of the product
                 "quantity":1
              }]
            }
          }
        }); 
//End

//Tracking removes from cart
        dataLayer.push({
           "event":"EEremoveFromCart",
           "ecommerce": {
             "currencyCode": curr,
             "remove": {
               "products": [{
                 "id": pdc,
                 "name": GarmName,
                 "price": prix,
                 "brand": "MyBrand",
//               "category":"Men/Clothing/T-Shirts",
//               "variant":"black", //optional, if there is a variant of the product
//               "quantity":1
              }]
            }
          }
        }); 
//End
```

I'm currently using the following code which **does** populate the data layer, but using Google Tag Manager, no data is being sent to Google Analytics except the purchase process.

```
    //Measuring Views of Product Details
        dataLayer.push({
          event: 'ProductView',
          ecommerce: {
            detail: {
              actionField: {
                list: 'Search Results'
              },
              products: [{
                id: pdc,
                name: GarmName,
//              category: 'guides/google-tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce',
//              variant: 'Text',
//              brand: 'SIMO AHAVA',
//              dimension3: 'Ecommerce',
//              metric5: 12,
//              metric6: 1002
              }]
            }
          }
        }); 
//END

//Measuring Product Clicks
        dataLayer.push({
        event: 'EE_ProductView',
        'ecommerce': {
        'detail': {
            'actionField': {},
                'products': [{
                    'name': GarmName,
                    'price': prix,
                    'id': pdc
                    }]
                }
            }
        })
//End

//Measuring Additions or Removals from a Shopping Cart
        dataLayer.push({
          'event': 'addToCart',
          'ecommerce': {
            'currencyCode': curr,
            'add': {
              'products': [{
                'name': GarmName,
                'id': pdc,
                'price': prix,
                'quantity': 1
               }]
            }
          }
        });
//End

// Measure the removal of a product from a shopping cart.
        dataLayer.push({
          'event': 'removeFromCart',
          'ecommerce': {
            'remove': {
              'products': [{
                  'name': GarmName,
                  'id': pdc,
                  'price': prix,
                  'quantity': 1
              }]
            }
          }
        });
//End
```

What am I doing wrong for one set of code to work and another to not?  And how can I get GTM to push the data it is receiving to Google Analytics, please?

Many Thanks

EDIT:  I've deleted my code and GTM/GA tags and rewritten them all and it seems to now be working to an extent.  Still getting the same issues though so will look into this further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted all code and tags, and started from scratch.  Changing some of the tags from 'event' to 'page view' and vice versa seems to have fixed the issue I was having.
Data is now being pushed to DataLayer and is picked up by GA.

Thanks to all for your help

Answer (score 1):

Looking at you tag, your EE_ProductView trigger is set for PageView, which is firing before you are pushing data to your dataLayer.  It depends when you are pushing items to the dataLayer as to which trigger you would want to use.  You can probably use a Window Loaded trigger if you are pushing items to the dataLayer as part of the page load.  For events that occur after page load (e.g., clicks), you can use a Custom Event trigger that fires on the event name (e.g., "EE_ProductView").

Comment: I've tried changing to Window Loaded but this hasn't rectified the issue, and most of the triggers are custom triggers too.  
Watching the real time, I can see data being transferred when clicking 'add to cart', but nothing else so I'm now wondering if the issue lies with the code itself

Comment: When you look at the left column in Tag Manager preview, are you seeing the events you are looking for?  Every time you push to the data layer you should see an event/message.  If it does appear, does it show any tags under "Tags Fired On This Event" on the Tags tab?

Comment: The 'add to cart' one seems to be working - the tag is firing on click as it should.  
The main issue seems to be with the 'product view' which isn't firing properly, but details are still getting through to GA as 'undefined' or 'NULL' depending on whether I use a variable in the tag

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a screenshot of your tag in GTM, do you have correct triggers on your tag, and do those triggers even happen on the website?

Comment: Tags are firing no problem - can see them fire using the debug option of GTM. 
Image of the product view tag is here for you https://imgur.com/khYDGIa